# undefined method `path' for "json":String during soundcloud track upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soundcloud

In a Rails application, I am using the SoundCloud gem (https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby), to upload a sound file to SoundCloud with the following code. The file is uploaded from a form using a file type input.

```ruby
def upload
  @api_response = @soundcloud.post('/tracks', :track => {
    :title => params[:title],
    :asset_data => params[:sound].tempfile
  })
end
```

`@soundcloud` is the SoundCloud client created in a `before_filter`.

When I try to upload a file, I get this error:

```ruby
NoMethodError (undefined method `path' for "json":String):
  app/controllers/api_controller.rb:223:in `upload'
```

I am having a hard time understanding the root cause of the error. Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty/issues/19) notes that using Ruby 1.9 may work around the problem.

Comment: @mccannf thanks for the pointer. I updated my bundle and now it works better.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This code.**

def upload

```
   file = params[:sound]
   title = params[:title]
   track = client.post('/tracks', track: {
      title: title
      asset_data: File.new(file.tempfile, 'rb')
      })
```

end